# how to split time stamped data as train and test

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, train-test-split

I have a dataset with timestamped given below:

```
date        type, price
1990-01-01, 'A', 100
1990-01-02, 'A', 200
1990-01-03, 'A', 300
1990-01-04, 'A', 400
1990-01-05, 'A', 500
1990-01-06, 'A', 600
1990-01-07, 'A', 700
1990-01-08, 'A', 800
1990-01-09, 'A', 900
1990-01-10, 'A', 1000
1990-01-11, 'B', 1100
1990-01-12, 'B', 1200
1990-01-13, 'B', 1300
1990-01-14, 'B', 1400
1990-01-15, 'B', 1500
```

I am trying to split this data as train and test with keeping the order based on `date`. If the split ratio is 0.8 for train and test, the expected output is supposed to be the following data:
**train_data:**

```
date        type, price
1990-01-01, 'A', 100
1990-01-02, 'A', 200
1990-01-03, 'A', 300
1990-01-04, 'A', 400
1990-01-05, 'A', 500
1990-01-06, 'A', 600
1990-01-07, 'A', 700
1990-01-08, 'A', 800
1990-01-11, 'B', 1100
1990-01-12, 'B', 1200
1990-01-13, 'B', 1300
1990-01-14, 'B', 1400
```

**test_data:**

```
    date        type, price
    1990-01-09, 'A', 900
    1990-01-10, 'A', 1000
    1990-01-15, 'B', 1500
```

Is there any way to do this in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 0):

transform & transform

```
# grouper
g = df.groupby("type", sort=False).type

# first is 1..size second is [size, size, ...]
sample_nos  = g.transform("cumcount").add(1)
group_sizes = g.transform("size")

# belongs to training or not
train_mask = sample_nos <= 0.8 * group_sizes

# then choose so
train_data = df[train_mask].copy()
test_data  = df[~train_mask].copy()
```

```
train_data

          date type  price
0   1990-01-01  'A'    100
1   1990-01-02  'A'    200
2   1990-01-03  'A'    300
3   1990-01-04  'A'    400
4   1990-01-05  'A'    500
5   1990-01-06  'A'    600
6   1990-01-07  'A'    700
7   1990-01-08  'A'    800
10  1990-01-11  'B'   1100
11  1990-01-12  'B'   1200
12  1990-01-13  'B'   1300
13  1990-01-14  'B'   1400
```

and

```
test_data

          date type  price
8   1990-01-09  'A'    900
9   1990-01-10  'A'   1000
14  1990-01-15  'B'   1500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` methods to split the data.

### Code:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data as string
s = '''date,type,price
1990-01-01,A,100
1990-01-02,A,200
1990-01-03,A,300
1990-01-04,A,400
1990-01-05,A,500
1990-01-06,A,600
1990-01-07,A,700
1990-01-08,A,800
1990-01-09,A,900
1990-01-10,A,1000
1990-01-11,B,1100
1990-01-12,B,1200
1990-01-13,B,1300
1990-01-14,B,1400
1990-01-15,B,1500'''

# Read the sample
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

# Ensure that df is sorted by date at least
df = df.sort_values(['type', 'date']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Split df into train and test dataframes
split_ratio = 0.8
train_data = df.groupby('type', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.head(int(split_ratio * len(df))))
test_data = df[~df.index.isin(train_data.index)]
```

### Output:

#### # train_data:

|  | date | type | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1990-01-01 | A | 100 |
| 1 | 1990-01-02 | A | 200 |
| 2 | 1990-01-03 | A | 300 |
| 3 | 1990-01-04 | A | 400 |
| 4 | 1990-01-05 | A | 500 |
| 5 | 1990-01-06 | A | 600 |
| 6 | 1990-01-07 | A | 700 |
| 7 | 1990-01-08 | A | 800 |
| 10 | 1990-01-11 | B | 1100 |
| 11 | 1990-01-12 | B | 1200 |
| 12 | 1990-01-13 | B | 1300 |
| 13 | 1990-01-14 | B | 1400 |

#### # test_data:

|  | date | type | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1990-01-09 | A | 900 |
| 9 | 1990-01-10 | A | 1000 |
| 14 | 1990-01-15 | B | 1500 |